# Database design. Hierarchy in select query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-performance

Here are some of my tables:
Projects > Project Categories > Sub Categories > Items > Versions

If I want to loop out all the items with their selected current version is there any performance loss in doing a `SELECT * FROM projects` and making JOINS all the way to versions, rather than `SELECT * FROM items` and making the JOINS from there?

My queries starting to become a little tricky and building them from the highest level and down seems logical, but on the other hand asking for posts from the table I actually want the main result from seems speedier and straight to the point?

Basically, will it scan through a lot more posts in the first option than the second?

Comment: It sounds like you're selecting the same data from the same tables, but just changing the order you're doing the joins in? If so, I _don't think_ it would make a difference. The fact you're joining product to product categories is the same as joining product categories to products. **I may be wrong though.**

Comment: I think the query optimiser should work either way. why not code them both and try it - and run EXPLAIN on each - to see whether you can see the difference

Comment: In my mind the two questions would be: 1) In this project, join categories, join sub categories, join items and current version 2) Select items with current versions from this project with these categories and sub categories. Apples and pears I guess. "grab 10 balls out of that bucket on the left side" vs "in that bucket to the left grab 10 balls" :)

Comment: When I started from the items I ran into problem of keys not being joint already. There's probably a way around it, but I like starting from top and narrow it down if it doesn't effect the speed. I'll do some testing. Thanks!

Comment: imo, Write the query in the clearest and the easiest to understand manner. Then run it and ensure it returns the correct results. Ok, you now have a working query. :) Now time it on useful amounts of data. Is it fast enough? Stop. Otherwise: Explain plan and start trying to optimize it....